# Send file via Jersey and x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, jersey

I'm trying to invoke REST service with the following client code with the idea to send some String message details as well as the attachment file:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getClasses().add(FormProvider.class);
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://some.url/path1/path2");

File attachment = new File("./file.zip");

FormDataBodyPart fdp = new FormDataBodyPart(
            "content", 
            new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(attachedLogs))),
            MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);
form.bodyPart(fdp);

ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, form);
```

The server I'm targeting accepts Base64 encoded content, so that is why the additional transferring from File to ByteArray.

Also, I have found that class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider is noted with both for production and consuming of "x-www-form-urlencoded" requests.

```
@Produces({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "*/*"})
@Consumes({"application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "*/*"})
```

But still I end-up with the following stacktrace:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: A message body writer for Java type, class com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataMultiPart, and MIME media type, application/x-www-form-urlencoded, was not found at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:149) ~[jersey-client-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648) ~[jersey-client-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:670) ~[jersey-client-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:563) ~[jersey-client-1.9.1.jar:1.9.1]
```

Any help on this one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get the thing working on the client side. The problem was that I was forcing sending of file as separate message body part, while [x-www-form-urlencoded is actually packing all of the data as parameters in the query that is the entire body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application/x-www-form-urlencoded).

So the working client code if you want to send attachment via Jersey post method would be:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://some.url/path1/path2");

MultivaluedMapImpl values = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
values.add("filename", "report.zip");
values.add("text", "Test message");
values.add("content", new String(Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(attachedLogs))));
ClientResponse response = webResource.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED).post(ClientResponse.class, values);
```

The Apache Commons' Base64 encoder was required in my case to transform file into encoded byte array, not sure if this is general requirement.

Comment: Using multipart is more efficient if you are uploading files, but working is good.  If you want to try multipart, set your accept to "multipart/form-data" and then use the FormDataMultiPart from the client for all parts you want to send (files, fields etc).

Comment: Note: for fields use .field("name", "value").

Answer (score 1):

try using `Multipart/form-data` instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. [This tutorial](http://aruld.info/handling-multiparts-in-restful-applications-using-jersey/) might help.

Comment: thanks Alex, but I cannot control the server side in is case so switching to multipart is not an option.